# MPAndroidChart: How to set axis value?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to create a radar chart. However, I am having trouble setting the x-axis.

Currently, I want to display the values ​​of [40, 50, 60, 70] as [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80].

Please help me. This is how to initialize the chart.

```
    RadarChart radarChart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        radarChart = findViewById(R.id.mapsearchdetail_radar_chart);

        RadarDataSet dataSet1 = new RadarDataSet(dataValue1(), " ");

        dataSet1.setColor(Color.RED);
        dataSet1.setValueTextSize(18f);

        RadarData data1 = new RadarData();
        data1.addDataSet(dataSet1);

        XAxis xAxis = radarChart.getXAxis();

        xAxis.setLabelCount(20, false);
        xAxis.setAxisMaximum(100f);
        xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);

        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels));
        radarChart.setData(data1);

        radarChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);   // Hide the legend
        radarChart.invalidate();



    }


    private ArrayList<RadarEntry> dataValue1(){
        ArrayList<RadarEntry> dataVals = new ArrayList<>();
        dataVals.add(new RadarEntry(52));
        dataVals.add(new RadarEntry(38));
        dataVals.add(new RadarEntry(48));
        dataVals.add(new RadarEntry(58));
        dataVals.add(new RadarEntry(66));

        return  dataVals;
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S20ha.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you need to set yAxis

```
chart.getYAxis().setAxisMinimum(0);
chart.getYAxis().setAxisMaximum(80);
chart.getYAxis().setLabelCount(9, true);
```